# Need help installing Canon D530 drivers

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

The default printer app didn't pick the right drivers so I installed the drivers from the Canon website which gave me a tar.gz file that I extracted and now I have the folder with the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers in there. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and wondering how I would I install the drivers so it can make my printer work.

Comment: http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/04/13/how-to-install-printer-driver-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: You can use MP3010 for this printer. And that one is in the default driver database ;)

Comment: I didn't find the MP3010 driver in the Canon database. Is there a way to install the drivers that I got from the website?

Comment: look in the directories that were created on extracting the file. There should be a file ending in .sh This is a shell script and you need to make it executable (if it's not already) and run it (usually with root privileges) with a command like 'sudo ./script.sh'

Answer (score 2):

I have to exact same printer scanner etc. All I did was download the drivers from canon (Linux version of drivers). It will say OS system detected Linux. You have to agree to the terms and conditions. Download the drivers, I then used Ubuntu software centre to install the drivers. There is RPM and Debian Driver folders in the Main folder you will see them. I used the Debian 32 bit driver and installed both driver files that are in there. One driver file is something like 1.5 and the other is 13.3. Maybe diff dep on OS architecture. After the Go and add you printer and it should find the printer and install the drivers that are already installed. I then printed a test page to make sure that it all worked. Now the only thing left for me to do is get the scanner working. LOL